# Is "alarmed by the clock" a parenthesis or participle clause in this sentence?

Tags: parsing, participle-clauses, functions

> Tony nervously watched the woman, **alarmed by the clock**.

In this sentence, is *alarmed by the clock* a parenthesis or a participle clause modifying object *Tony*?

Comment: My vote is on participle clause.  With the comma it modifies 'Tony', without the comma - 'woman'.

Comment: I'd say it's both, as might be more obvious if we move it to become *Tony, **alarmed by the clock,** nervously watched the woman.* But in any case, it modifies the ***subject** (Tony)*, not the ***object** (the woman)*